# how to make derived attribute that get data from another table column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
Item (ID, name, logo, description, categoryID)
Review (ID, item_id, name, body, rating)
```

I want to add derived attribute `overall_ratinq` in `item` table

I know that I have to get average rating by id but every syntax I do doesn't work.

I have already created the tables.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) feature does not support subqueries or calling stored functions. I don't think there's any way to make a generated column include values from a different table.

You could do this with a trigger. That is, add a real column to the `Item` table:

```
ALTER TABLE Item ADD COLUMN overall_rating INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Then use triggers on INSERT and UPDATE to the `Review` table, to incrementally adjust the stored value in the Item table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER review_ins AFTER INSERT ON Review
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE Item SET overall_rating = overall_rating + NEW.rating
  WHERE ID = NEW.item_id;

CREATE TRIGGER review_upd AFTER UPDATE ON Review
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE Item SET overall_rating = overall_rating - OLD.rating + NEW.rating
  WHERE ID = NEW.item_id;
```

I have not tested these examples. I'll leave it to you to test and modify to your needs. There are probably edge cases that it doesn't handle, like what if the UPDATE changed the `item_id`?

Note also that this will result in locks on rows in the `Item` table when reviews are posted.

If you don't want to do this, then use a VIEW, to calculate the overall_rating on demand:

```
CREATE VIEW ItemsWithRatings AS
  SELECT ID, name, logo, description, categoryID, 
    SUM(Review.rating) AS overall_rating
  FROM Item JOIN Review ON Review.item_id=Item.ID
  GROUP BY Item.ID;
```